# Force make to execute commands in the same environment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile to compile a cross-platform application. For Windows, I've decided to use MSVC. To set up the compiler toolchain (environment variables to easily access compiler for a specific target architecture), MSVC provides a batch file called `vcvarsall`. If I invoke it manually, it works fine and the makefile can execute too. I've tried to automatize it a bit by invoking it from the makefile, but make seems to run it in a different environment, so it fails to find the compiler.

Is there a way to force make not to execute some commands in a different environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make, like all processes, runs in the environment with which it is started.
*Each* line of a recipe that it executes runs in a *distinct* subprocess, specifically,
a distinct invocation of the shell. A subprocess cannot do anything to change the environment of
its parent process or of a sibling subprocess: it can only pass a modified environment
to its own subprocesses.

```
targetA: prequisitesA...
    command1        # New shell; inherits environment of `make`
    command2        # Another new shell; inherits environment of `make`
    ...

targetB: prequisitesB...
    command1 && command2    # New shell; inherits environment of `make`
    command3        # Another new shell; inherits environment of `make`
    ...

targetC: prequisitesC...
    command1 && \
    command2    # New shell; inherits environment of `make`
    command3; \
    command4    # Another new shell; inherits environment of `make`
    ...
```

To make use within a command in a make-recipe of any environment settings that
are applied by running `vcvarsall` then either `make` must be run after
`vcvarsall` in the same environment or an inherited one that preserves those
settings, or else the same must be true of each recipe command that depends
on those settings.

You can direct Make to run all the commands of each recipe in *one* shell,
per recipe, by writing the pseudo-target [`.ONESHELL:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html)
in the makefile. But this seems unlikely to be a fix for you.

Probably a suitable automation for your case is to write a wrapper
script that invokes `vcvarsall` before `make`.

Depending on how your makefile is structured, and your tolerance for recursive make, you might fancy a recursive solution, in the vein:

```
ARCH ?= amd64

.PHONY: all

all:
    vcvarsall $(ARCH) && $(MAKE) prog
```

where:-

- `ARCH` (architecture) defaults to `amd64` if not defined on the `make`
  commandline or in the calling environment
- `all` is your default target phony target
- `prog` is your real target.

Comment: Right now I'm considering writing the wrapper. But it seemed so convenient to have a rule called Win32Debug for example that just calls vcvarsall with x86 argument (or x64 if invoked Win64Debug). Writing a wrapper means a lot of duplications in configuratin checking.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi Maybe you would go recursive - see update.